# Why does lubridate::mdy() add day when it is missing from my input?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am purposefully leaving out the day in this code and am expecting it to fail, return a warning, or return an incomplete record.

```
txt <-  "January 2010"
lubridate::mdy(txt)
```

The output is "2010-01-20". Why does it include '20' when the day is not my input? What is the logic behind that value?

Comment: Because Date includes a day as well.  You may need `lubridate::myd(paste(txt, '01'))`

Comment: Well no doubt, but why 20 and not some other number in the range of 0-31? Or is it random?

Comment: The `mdy` is looking for month day and year.  Here, day is missing and it assumes the 2 digit 20 as day and the last 2 digit as year for 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the order of parsing.  According to `?mdy`

> In case of heterogeneous date formats, the ymd() family guesses formats based on a subset of the input vector. If the input vector contains many missing values or non-date strings, the subset might not contain meaningful dates

The original string includes month followed by 4 digit year and `mdy` is `month`, `day` `year` and `year` can be either 2 digit or 4 digit.  Now, there is a confusion and it selects 2 digit year as '10' and the day are parsed as '20'.  Instead, if we add a day and then use `mdy`, it would parse as 4 digit year

```
lubridate::myd(paste(txt, '01'))
#[1] "2010-01-01"
```